# Pivottable.js filter dialog box button size

Tags: css, plotly.js, pivottable.js

In my [pivottable](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/), when I clicked a field to open the filter box, its "Apply" & "Cancel" buttons are too small.

[image]

Using this style also can't make them bigger:

```
.pvtFilterBox{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it is nothing to do with styling.

This is because I defined the locales for 'totals' only. It won't use default locales for other words (Apply, Cancel, etc).

```
$.pivotUtilities.locales.en = {
          localeStrings: {
                totals: "TOTALS"
          }
};
```